# Keep programs in memory to open faster

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, memory

I use my computer mainly for Google Chrome, so I want make it open as quickly as possible. Is it possibly to keep Google Chrome running in the background at all times? I want it to work like mobile apps, where a closed application stays in memory.

Comment: so just dont exit Chrome..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows Vista, 7, or 8 then SuperFetch is very likely already keeping Chrome in memory. http://www.osnews.com/story/21471/SuperFetch_How_it_Works_Myths

Turning off your page file might be tempting, but is a bad idea if you don't have 8+ GB of RAM. Modern Windows is pretty good about managing the page file, and is generally best left alone. http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it

Another option is to just always leave Chrome open. It runs separate processes for each tab, so if you close all open tabs but one it will give you back all that memory.

Comment: I have an SSD so having page file seems a little wasteful in terms of SSD's life expectancy. But luckily i have 8GB and no problems with page file turned off.

Comment: @pantsburgh normally disabling a pagefile is not advised, however under special circumstances like this one where the person mainly runs Chrome, it's not a bad idea. I am responsible for many servers and workstations and have played with a lot of variations on pagefile settings. There are some boundary conditions where the absence of pagefile hurts. e.g. a runaway process starts hogging memory and ultimately can crash windows, but again, running Chrome means there'll be nothing lost, just an unfortunate restart of the machine and few minutes of delay.

Comment: LMSingh, if a person mainly runs Chrome and they have plenty of spare memory then Superfetch is already keeping Chrome in memory.
If it's not already in memory then turning off the page file will not help Chrome load faster, since it loads off the hard drive regardless. Recommending average users to mess with page file settings is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome in Advaced settings you can set..
    "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"

Even without the above setting though Chrome always keeps a hidden process in windows. So a part of your idea is already being done by Chrome. (edited).. NOTE: I did find a system where Chrome didn't stay in memory.. so I wasn't entirely correct.

Additionally you can check my [suggestions in the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/396964/how-to-make-windows-7-switch-between-programs-faster-after-a-while/728298#728298) to a related question. Here I recommend a few things including not removing pagefile but setting it very small.

Another person mentioned to never close Chrome.. (edited) in most systems, it keeps running in the background. Most users just don't see it. Run Task Manager or Process Explorer and you'll see it in memory as an active process all the time. If on your machine it does close automatically, then it is a little bit helpful to keep it running.

Reference:

[How to make Windows 7 switch between programs faster after a while?](https://superuser.com/questions/396964/how-to-make-windows-7-switch-between-programs-faster-after-a-while/728298#728298)

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7, Control panel->View Advanced system settings, Advanced Tab, Performance Settings, Advanced, go to   Virtual memory-> Change. Check no paging file.